# Return value from function which calls itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I have some function which calls itself:

```
def rep_func(parent_id, account_id):
    ...

    for page in iterator:
        for item in page['Children']:
            if id == item['Id']:
                //return parent_id
                
    for page in org_iterator:
        for ou in page['Children']:
            rep_func(ou['Id'], account_id)
```

I need to return the `parent_id` from the function when the `if` is succesfull. How can I do this?  Do I need a `break`?

Comment: What do you expect to do with the values of `rep_func(ou['Id'], account_id)` in your second loop? Right now, you don't do anything.

Comment: I want to call the function again with the new values? So I'm looping over my function and during one of those runs the if is successfull.

Comment: Yes, you call the function with new values, it returns a result. What do you want to do with the result?

Comment: the parent_id should be used in a different function later on, the other results are not important to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the value; this automatically breaks the current loop.

For the recursive case, I'm guessing you want to check whether any value was found, and return it conditionally, so that the loop will keep searching if the recursive call was unsuccessful:

```
def rep_func(parent_id, account_id):
    # ...

    for page in iterator:
        for item in page['Children']:
            if id == item['Id']:
                return parent_id
                
    for page in org_iterator:
        for ou in page['Children']:
            if result := rep_func(ou['Id'], account_id):
                return result

    # we implicitly return None if no match found
```

Comment: Note the walrus operator requires 3.8 or newer.